# How to schedule taskscheduleR once a month at the start of every month?

Tags: r, r-taskscheduler

Looking to run R script once a month at the first of every month.I've figured out how to run it via task scheduler with the  taskscheduleR library. Here is the current cadence I have set on it:

```
taskscheduler_create(taskname = "Rebate Automation2", rscript = myscript, 
                     schedule = "MONTHLY", starttime = "12:30")
```

I am unsure how to set it for the first of every month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the package documentation:

```
days     character string with days on which to run the script if schedule is
’WEEKLY’or ’MONTHLY’. Possible values are * (all days). For weekly: ’MON’,
’TUE’,’WED’, ’THU’, ’FRI’, ’SAT’, ’SUN’ or a vector of these in your locale. 
For monthly: 1:31 or a vector of these.
```

Therefore `taskscheduler_create(taskname = "Rebate Automation2", rscript = myscript, schedule = "MONTHLY", days=1, starttime = "12:30")`

Should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `taskscheduleR::taskscheduler_create` can be found (1) by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> and clicking on the function call `taskscheduler_create`; or (2) on pages 3 and 4 of the [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/taskscheduleR/taskscheduleR.pdf).  Per this documentation, the `days` parameter

```
taskscheduler_create(
  ...
  days = c("*", "MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT", "SUN", 1:31),
  ...
)
```

can be set to `days = 1` for `schedule = "MONTHLY"`, to trigger on the first day of every month:

> character string with days on which to run the script if schedule is ’WEEKLY’
> or ’MONTHLY’. Possible values are * (all days). For weekly: ’MON’, ’TUE’,
> ’WED’, ’THU’, ’FRI’, ’SAT’, ’SUN’ or a vector of these in your locale. For
> monthly: 1:31 or a vector of these.

So you'd want to use

```
taskscheduler_create(taskname = "Rebate Automation2", rscript = myscript, 
                     schedule = "MONTHLY", days = 1, starttime = "12:30")
#                                          ^^^^^^^^
```